# Delete multiple rows in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a database consisting of several tables that are common in the project name field
I created a form with a subform to search
While typing the project name, all the records in the table are filtered until I finally reach the desired record.

My question is whether it is possible to create a button that deletes all records related to this project in all tables.

Comment: You may run multiple delete query with project name criteria.

Comment: The answer will probably be `Yes`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set up *Referential Integrity* betweeen the tables. Official documentation:

[How to define relationships between tables in an Access database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/define-table-relationships?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Though you should read it all, the key paragraphs are:

- Referential integrity
- Cascading updates and deletes